# How to make PKGBUILD install to /usr/bin/ with dependencies?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman

I'm writing a PKGBUILD for [meetalva.io](https://meetalva.io) so I can submit it to AUR—so others can install it through `yaourt`.

The binary `Alva` has two library dependencies, `libnode.so` and `libffmpeg.so`, which I need to include otherwise I get `alva: error while loading shared libraries: libnode.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

I can't simply copy these two `.so` files into `/usr/bin`, so what's the best practice here? I feel like I want to copy the binary and `.so` files into `/usr/lib` then create a symlink `/usr/lib/alva-git/Alva` -> `/usr/bin/Alva` but I'm not managing to get the symlinking working.

Thanks in advance.

---

## `PKGBUILD`:

```
_pkgname="alva"
pkgname="${_pkgname}-git"
pkgver=v0.8.0
pkgrel=1
pkgdesc="Create living prototypes with code components."
arch=("i686" "x86_64")
url="https://meetalva.io"
license=('MIT')
groups=()
depends=(gconf libxss nss gtk3)
makedepends=(git npm nodejs)
optdepends=()
provides=(alva)
conflicts=(alva)
replaces=()
backup=()
options=()
install=
changelog=
source=("${pkgname}::git+http://github.com/meetalva/${_pkgname}.git")
noextract=()
md5sums=(SKIP)

# https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VCS_package_guidelines
pkgver() {
  cd "$srcdir/$pkgname"
# Use latest tag
  git tags|tail -n 1
}

build() {
  cd "$pkgname"
  last_tag=$( git tags|tail -n 1 )
  git checkout $last_tag
  npm install
  npm run build
  npm run build:electron || true
}

package() {
  cd "$pkgname" # enter git repo
  install -D -m 644 LICENSE "${pkgdir}/usr/share/licenses/$pkgname/LICENSE"
  mkdir -p "${pkgdir}/usr/bin/"
  cp -f dist/linux-unpacked/Alva "${pkgdir}/usr/bin/alva"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an Electron app, so you need to copy the *entire* `linux-unpacked/` directory to `/opt/alva/`, then make a symlink into `"${pkgdir}"/usr/bin/Alva` for the binary itself which is merely a renamed `electron` binary.

All the actual alva code will be in the `resources/app/` directory (or app.asar file in some cases). The ideal packaging method would be to simply use the system electron package (available in the [community] repository).

Install this app resources directory/file to e.g. `/usr/share/alva/` or `/usr/share/alva.asar` (if there are no compiled node modules) or `/usr/lib/alva/` (if there *are* compiled modules), then create a shell script wrapper for `/usr/bin/alva` which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec electron /usr/share/alva/ "$@"
```